# I want to get my Graph API token but I got an error, I'm making a POST request with HttpServices. I'm getting a 400 status code. I'm using NestJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, microsoft-graph-api, nestjs

```
**This is my code when I'm creating the class and the method:**

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftGraph {
constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {} 
  getMicrosoftGraphToken() {
    const data = {
      client_id: 'myclientid',
      scope: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
      client_secret: 'myclientsecret',
      grant_type: 'client_credentials'
    }
const url = 
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token';
    const response = this.httpService.post(url, data).pipe(
      tap((resp) => console.log(resp)),
      map((resp) => resp.data),
      tap((data) =>  console.log(data)),
    );
    console.log(response);
    return response;
  }
}
```

**This is the part of the controller:**

```
@Controller('user')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly microsoftGraph: MicrosoftGraph) {} 
  @Get('hola')
  intento(@Res() res: Response, @Req() req: Request){
    return this.microsoftGraph.getMicrosoftGraphToken();
  }
}
```

**And this is the error I'm getting:**

```
Observable {
  source: Observable {
    source: Observable {
      source: [Observable],
      operator: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    operator: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}
[Nest] 19464  - 08/30/2022, 8:05:31 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Request failed with status code 400
[Nest] 19464  - 08/30/2022, 8:05:31 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] undefined
```

I'm trying to get this token to be able to make a function where I can pull a list of users in my company, please help and thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you solved this already, but the problem is in your URL. You have hardcoded the tenantId part. So instead of:

```js
const url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/mytenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token';
```

It should probably be something like this:

```js
const graphTenantId = `1234-abcd-etc-etc`;
const url = 
`https://login.microsoftonline.com/${graphTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token`;
```

The way you are currently doing it, is that you are trying to get the tenant with ID "mytenantid".

Also, since you are using NestJS, I would advise you to use the .env file to save the data that you now put in your "data" constant and similar to the tenant_id that you still need to add. This of course only applies when these values are set in stone. [The NestJS documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration) has a great summary on how to do this.

If you have dynamic data in regards to the Graph API (so you would have clients that would connect through your NestJS application), you can probably best make a GraphConfiguration object which you then get using a service (that's the way I did it).

Hope this helps you!